# Zoom Core Graphics in UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiscrollview, core-animation, core-graphics

I was wondering which would be the best way to scale my Core Graphics drawings as I zoomed in using a UIView subclass within a UIScrollView.

Currently when I zoom in, the drawing becomes slightly fuzzy - I know this is correct functioning, I just want to know how developers override it to keep the image sharp...

Thanks!

(P.s. I have heard about using Core Animation, but I don't know where to start on that huge library with scary names haha!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest way is to use supersampling. Basically, create your image at a larger resolution than it's displayed at, and scale it down for display (UIImageView will scale it for you). Then when you zoom in, it will simply be scaling back up to the original resolution.

The downside to this approach is you can't scale your image up too large or it will take up too much memory.

Comment: what do you mean by "image" is that "core graphics drawing"? (sorry, I sound like a noob - low level C/assembly are my more natural languages) and also, I am drawing it in a UIView (not a UIImageView - does that matter...?) thanks! :)

Comment: Ah, you're not drawing a separate image. I gotcha. You can still do this same thing, by simply creating your view to be larger than it used to be and setting the zoom scale on the scrollview such that it's zoomed out by default. Then when the user zooms in they're really just zooming it back to its normal size.

Comment: Thankyou so much! But because I have 1px black borders around white boxes, the borders become anti-aliased. Should just turn off anti-aliasing or something?