# Scale Core Graphics drawings i.e. zoom without loss of quality

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics, scale

I would like to scale my drawings in `-drawRect:` without stretching the original (lossless). Is there a way to scale everything up to create a zoom effect ? Let's say I draw a circle in `-drawRect:` with a size of, say 20x20 and then I would go ahead and pinch on my view. Is there a way to tell this hypothetical `Circle` class to draw everything twice or multiple times the size ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964083/zoom-core-graphics-in-uiscrollview and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5889517/zoomable-graphics. Basically, you are drawing *pixels*, not *objects*. The suggested answers prefer drawing large and displaying small, so you can zoom in. A slower but better alternative would be to create a stack of draw primitives and scale mathematically (and it'd be slow because you have to check *every* object, although some basic grid caching may help with this).

Comment: You might give `contentsScale` a try if you are using a `CALayer` for rendering CoreGraphics drawings.

Comment: @Martin E. you can use `CATiledLayer` for the same, it prevents loss of quality. Good Luck

Comment: Thanks I will try all three of these and see which works best!